# Retrieving values from array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am  working on a angular application. I have an array as follows.

```
[
    { 
     Code: "123",
     Details:[
       {
        Id: "1",
        Name: "Gary"
       },
       {
        Id: "2",
        Name: "Rocky"
       }]
    },
    { 
     Code: "456",
     Details:[
       {
        Id: "3",
        Name: "Cindy"
       },
       {
        Id: "4",
        Name: "Jacky"
       }]
    }
]
```

There can be many more elements. This array contains Code, Array of Details(can be of any length)- This detail array contains Id and Name. I have Id coming from query params. I need to see id that Id matches in Details array and get Code for that. For example, If Id coming from query param is 4, then I need to retrieve Code value i.e 456. If Id value is 2 then I need to retrieve Code value i.e 123. How I can do that?

Comment: It's not an array

Comment: `let {Code} = (arr.find(({Details}) => Details.some(({Id}) => Id === 4)) || {}); //If not found, undefined will be assigned`

Comment: @Ele Where it is giving code

Comment: @Lozy destructuring assignment over the found object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the OP is working on an array of objects.

You can use the function `Array.prototype.find` along with the function `Array.prototype.some` to be able to identify a specific detail.

Finally, using the destructuring assignment we can extract the property `Code`.

```js
let arr = [{
  Code: "123",
  Details: [{
    Id: "1",
    Name: "Gary"
  }, {
    Id: "2",
    Name: "Rocky"
  }]
}, {
  Code: "456",
  Details: [{
    Id: "3",
    Name: "Cindy"
  }, {
    Id: "4",
    Name: "Jacky"
  }]
}];
let { Code } = arr.find(({ Details }) =>
Details.some(({ Id }) => Id === "4")) || {}; //If not found, undefined will be assigned

console.log(Code);
```